# Redirecting log entries - where have I gone wrong

Tags: linux, python-3

On a Pi Zero, I have two python scripts set up as systemd services.  Each has a .service file in /etc/systemd/system. Each has a .conf file in /etc/rsyslog.d that is intended to redirect syslog entries to a log file in my home dicectory.  One works fine.  The other doesn't, it logs to /var/log/syslog.  I am trying to understand the difference.

The .service file for the script whose log entries go to syslog, instead of the log file in my home directory:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/vid-rec.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=vidrec
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the .conf file:

```
if $programname=='vidrec' then /home/pi/mylog.log
& stop
```

The script:

```
import io
from gpiozero import Button
import picamera
from datetime import datetime
import syslog

trigger = Button(16)
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1280, 720)

stream = picamera.PiCameraCircularIO(camera, seconds=10)
camera.start_recording(stream, format='h264')
try:
    while True:
        camera.wait_recording(1)
        if trigger.is_pressed:
            now = datetime.now()
            syslog.syslog("ACTION")
            camera.wait_recording(10)
            stream.copy_to(str(now)+'.h264')
            syslog.syslog("Stream saved to disk")
finally:
    camera.stop_recording()
```

For the script whose log entries go to the log file in my home directory, where I intend them to go, there are the same service and conf files (with appropriate name changes).  There is no explicit logging in the script.  Log entries are initiated by:

```
call(['shutdown', '-h', 'now'], shell=False)
```

Comment: I would think `StandardOutput=syslog` and `StandardError=syslog` and `syslog.syslog("ACTION")` and `syslog.syslog("Stream saved to disk")` make it obvious why the output goes to syslog

Comment: Jaromanda, please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585758/how-to-redirect-output-of-systemd-service-to-a-file